# nuxt3 SSR redirect in component

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'd like to show 404 page after `asyncData`, but before client, in server - and return 404 as HTTP code.

now my code is:

(`pages/[...slugs.vue]`)

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { PageData } from '~/api';

  const { data } = await useAsyncData(async () => {
    if (process.client) return;

    // path = '/some-path', locale = 'en'

    const page = await PageData.fetch(path, locale); // wrapper for $fetch api req, returns Page | null

    if (!page) {
      showError({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' }); // this is not working;
    }

    useHead(page.head); // set page head - title and meta tags
    return { page };
  });
</script>
```

For some reason `showError` function is not rendering my `error.vue` file. Forced server error (for ex. 500 from syntax error) is working fine.

How can I force early escape to error page or show error layout + page instead of regular one?

Comment: have you tried `throw createError()` ?

Comment: yes, `throw createError(...)` is not working for me - only in `useAsyncData` scope, out of it async data works fine.